# Confusion in writing $f(z) = \bar{z}^2 / z$ as $u + iv$ form.

Tags: complex-analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3jPP.png)

I do not understand how to obtain $u$ and $v$ from the original function given. I know $z=x+iy$ and $\bar{z}=x-iy$.  So wouldn't the original function be $(x-iy)^2/(x+iy)$?  But how come the real and imaginary components are different in the solution of this problem provided in the picture I have attached? Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: Yes, you're missing something simple. Your expression and the expression given in the image are, in fact, equivalent: you just didn't simplify your expression. Hint: multiply the numerator and denominator by $x-iy$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct regarding the original question. However in order to separate the real and imaginary parts it is common practice to make the denominator entirely real and so you must multiply the numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate of the denominator first.

$$
\frac{(x-iy)^2}{x+iy} = \frac{(x-iy)^3}{x^2+y^2}
$$

From here you expand to get the textbook answer.

Comment: Wow! Not sure how I did not think to multiply the numerator and denominator by the conjugate, Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:)** With $z=x+iy$ use
$$\dfrac{\overline{z}^2}{z}.\dfrac{\overline{z}}{\overline{z}}=\dfrac{\overline{z}^3}{|z|^2}$$
here $\overline{z}=x-iy$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed, you have
$$ f(z) = \frac{(x-iy)^2}{x+iy}.$$

But you know this is a complex number, and you know that *every* complex number can be written as "some real number plus $i$ times some real number (possibly a different one)."
That is, something that looks like $u + iv$ where $u$ and $v$ are real.

The formula at the bottom of the picture is showing what $u$ and $v$ have to be in order for $u+iv$ to equal $f(z).$

Other answers give you big hints about how those formulas for $u$ and $v$ can be derived.

Answer (score 0):

You are right:  the question asks you to find the real and imaginary parts of $$\frac{(x-iy)^2}{x+iy}$$
Do you remember (possibly in high school) learning the technique of "rationalizing the denominator"?  That is, given an expression like $\frac{2}{3+\sqrt{5}}$, one writes
$$\frac{2}{3+\sqrt{5}}=\frac{2}{3+\sqrt{5}}\cdot\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{3-\sqrt{5}} = \frac{6-2\sqrt{5}}{9-5}=\frac{6-2\sqrt{5}}{4}=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Well, a similar technique works here.  Multiply both the numerator and the denominator of the fraction by the conjugate of the denominator, and collect all of the imaginary terms together.  You'll end up with the intended expression.